# C# - VSTO Worksheet Inheritance

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Here is my problem, 
I would like to loop through all sheets of workbook and call a public method present in every partial sheet Class (**sheet1.get_data**, etc...)
However, my method is not visible when I am looping ( even if it is declared as public in my sheets) 
Here is my code :

```
   foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets)
   {
       //Call Sheet.get_data method defined in every sheet of   Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets            
   }
```

I believe it is normal, as the method should be defined in final class and inherited by child classes but I don't know how to do  it (maybe define the get data method at workbook level)?

Any answer are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1, Write a Interface and make your [Worksheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class inherit them.(I am not 100% sure on this but I followed this approach for Ribbon classes)

2, Use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) instead to invoke the method

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:
[Walkthrough: Calling Code from VBA in a Visual C# Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608613.aspx)